# General topology query about neighborhood of a point

Tags: general-topology

Considering a simple example,

Is it always necessary for a neighborhood of a point $a$ (say) to always be defined as $(a-,a+)$, $>0$, on the real number line?

Can we not consider a neighborhood such as $(a-,a+ε)$, $ε>0$, $>0$? Can we extend this idea to $n$ dimensions?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can. However it is usually convenient to use the open interval $(a+\delta,a-\delta)$.

Note that in general a neighborhood of a point is any set in the space that includes an open set containing the point, so the interval $(a+\delta,a-\delta)$ is a neighborhood of every point within it. The set $(a,b]$, however is *not* a neighborhood of the point $b$.

Answer (score 0):

In topology, a neighborhood $\mathcal V$ of a point $a$ is by definition a set containing a open set $\mathcal O$ such that $a \in \mathcal O$.

In $\mathbb R$ (with the usual topology), the open sets are the sets $\mathcal O$ such that for every element $a \in \mathcal O$, there exists en interval $(a-\varepsilon, a+\varepsilon) \subset \mathcal O$ for an $\varepsilon > 0$. So the neighborhoods $\mathcal V$ of a point $a \in \mathbb R$ are the sets containing an interval of the form $(a-\varepsilon, a+\varepsilon)$. For example, $\mathbb R$ is a neighborhood of $0$ in $\mathbb R$, as are $[-\frac 12, \frac 12]$, $(-1, \frac13)$, $(-1, +\infty)$ $\ldots$ Note that $[0, 1)$ is not a neighborhood of $0$, for example.

In broader dimension, if $\|\cdot\|$ is a norm on $\mathbb R^n$, the neigborhoods of $a \in \mathbb R^n$ are the sets $\mathbb V$ containing an open ball $B(a, r)$ centered in $a$.